Minified js file using BuildBundlerMinifier Package
I am trying to minified highcharts.src.js using bundleconfig.json in asp.net core using BuildBundlerMinifier Package for that I have written the below code in bundleconfig.json
[
    {
        "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/highchart2.min.js",
        "inputFiles": [
            "wwwroot/lib/highcharts/highcharts.src.js"
        ],
        "minify": {
            "enabled": true,
            "renameLocals": false
        }
    }
]

but when I build the application it will display the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Just want to know is it possible to minified highcharts.src.js using BuildBundlerMinifier Package?

Could you tell me why do you want to minify the Highcharts src file, where you can just include the highcharts.js file which is already minififed.
